# Call __call__ method from both parents classes

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

I have classes:

```
class C1():
    def __call__(self,name='1'):
        self.name=name
        print(self.name)

class C2():
    def __call__(self,name='2'):
        self.name=name
        print(self.name)

class C3(C1, C2):
    def __call__(self,name='=>35'):
        super().__call__()
        self.name=name
        print(self.name)
```

The result:

```
1
=>35
```

But what I expect:

```
1
2
=>35
```

How to call this method from both parents classes?

Answer (score 1):

`super()` just gets the next in the method resolution order or "mro".
It doesn't magically call multiple methods at once.

Typically you would place a `super()` call in each class. That way it always resolves itself. In this case the last one in line will raise an `AttributeError`.

However you could get around this by checking if your method has the method you are trying to call in your parent class.

```
class C1():
    def __call__(self,name='1'):
        self.name=name
        print(self.name)
        # I'm sure ther is a more pythonic way to do this
        # but this just checks if your super class has a
        # call method before calling it
        # you could just try catch the AttributeError as well
        # either way, your IDE will probably complain about this.
        super_class = super()
        if hasattr(super_class, '__call__'):
            super_class.__call__()

class C2():
    def __call__(self,name='2'):
        self.name=name
        print(self.name)
        super_class = super()
        if hasattr(super_class, '__call__'):
            super_class.__call__()

class C3(C1, C2):
    def __call__(self,name='=>35'):
        super().__call__()
        self.name=name
        print(self.name)

foo = C3()
foo()
```